# Should I use IEnumerable or List for parameters from WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say that I have

```
[HttpPost("some/route")]
public void AddSomething([FromBody] QueryParameter parameter){
    DoSomething();
}
```

and my parameter is:

```
public class QueryParameter  {
   public int ElementId { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<int> YearIds{ get; set; }       
}
```

The question is: can I keep `IEnumerable<int>` or it should be `List<int>`?
What is better practice and why?

Comment: For starters, an endpoint should never return `void`, but rather `IActionResult` / `Task<IActionResult>` if asynchronous.

Comment: Then, as always, try for yourself instead of asking someone else whether your own code works or doesn't.

Comment: It works in both cases... That's why I'm asking. 
By the way why I have to return value always? I'm using .net core 2.1 and Angular 6 if it matters.

Comment: Because you need to be able to be explicit about the result, independent of the actual work done and the result of such operation.

Comment: Is there is any particular reason why should I do this. If I not expecting any error here? What's the diffrence between `void` and `IActionResult return OK()` both going to return 200.

Comment: As I said, it's always best to show that you intended to return 200. Further, if you are not returning any result, you should return 204 -- no content.